# Is border radius supposed to work the Firefox way or the Webkit way?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, webkit, css

Is border radius supposed to work the Firefox way or the Webkit way? Basically, in Firefox if the element with the border radius has overflow hidden the content is clipped by the radius, in Webkit it overflows. The Firefox way certainly seems by far the most obviously logical.

If that is how it is supposed to work does any one have any idea when Webkit is going to fix it or is this going to be one of those god awful IE6 style browser discrepancies?

Comment: Could you show us some code? http://jsfiddle.net/BuDyW/ gives me exactly the same result in Firefox 12 and Chrome 19.

Comment: That has an absolutely position inner div and its corners are cut in FF but not in webkit

Comment: Definately seems to be related to the clipping of absolute elements inside relative ones- it seems to do half the job- ie clips to the box but doesn't remove the corners which just seems wrong to me...

Comment: I simplified the example a little - http://jsfiddle.net/BuDyW/9/. Yes, the question is about clipping absolutely positioned elements inside elements with relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68196

Answer (score 0):

The way this currently works in Chrome is a bug.

I have posted to the Chrome developers and they have confirmed that and believe it will be fixed shortly. Follow progress on the link below

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/2245dc43377a067d